# How to answer installation questions during EasyEngine installation?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, user-input

I am trying to make a very basic script that installs EasyEngine on multiple servers. During the installation of EasyEngine it asks for your name and e-mail.
How can I define these in the script?

My script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@$s1 wget -qO ee rt.cx/ee
ssh root@$s1 bash ee #After this command I have to provide name and e-mail
ssh root@$s1 source /etc/bash_completion.d/ee_auto.rc

ssh root@$s2 wget -qO ee rt.cx/ee
ssh root@$s2 bash ee #After this command I have to provide name and e-mail
ssh root@$s2 source /etc/bash_completion.d/ee_auto.rc

ssh root@$s3 wget -qO ee rt.cx/ee
ssh root@$s3 bash ee #After this command I have to provide name and e-mail
ssh root@$s3 source /etc/bash_completion.d/ee_auto.rc
```

Also Bonus question. Anyone have an idea how to combine these 3 blocks into one?

Comment: Look into `expect`.  That's what it's for.

Comment: I did come accross expect when searching for an answer but I do not understand how it works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `expect`.  It's not difficult, and well worth learning.  The `autoexpect` command comes with it.  Just run it without any parameters, and it will start up a new shell for you.  Run your three commands against one host, then exit out of the shell.  It will create `script.exp` for you.  You'll need to clean it up a bit, especially putting in:

```
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 0]
```

to get the host from the command line.  Replace your `spawn ssh root@s1` with

```
spawn ssh root@$ipaddr
```

If hostnames or anything else host-specific shown up in an expect line, you'll want to clean it out.

If you have a lot of hosts to manage, I also recommend Ansible.

Comment: Okay, thank you :) I will try it. I am on a machine without a gui btw. so how does this work with it spinning up another shell?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/064dc33bba3e0670f01bda3f4bdae268.png
This is the script.exp file I have now. It all looks like chinese to me. don't understand any of it

Comment: Looks like you didn't exit out of the shell that before you tried to edit script.exp with nano.

Comment: after autoexpect I have to type these three commands? to one of the webservers? and then exit?

Comment: Right.  That will create the script.exp file.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/947dddb4b7fae18584ed7d902cf906b9.png
This is the only interactive part.
So what do I delete and what do I keep? from the script.exp

Comment: Nothing.  What you need to change is the `spawn` that run ssh.   You want a different host for each, which is what the `set ipaddr [lindex $argv 0]` is going to get off the command line.  Fix that (and anything that might have a hostname in it, like the bash prompt), and you can then run `script.exp host2`.

Comment: Did not get it to work yet but I do see how this would work now. I set your reaction as the answer :) Thanks for your help
I will try again after some sleep.

Comment: Thanks.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

EasyEngine will ask for Name and Email if it did not find in .gitconfig .

Try this:

```
bash -c 'echo -e "[user]\n\tname = abc\n\temail = root@localhost.com" > /root/.gitconfig'
```